# Using the "xxd -r" command does not convert entire ASCII to text

Tags: linux, xxd

I'm working on a CTF (Capture The Flag) challenge, and one of the flags is hidden in ASCII

```
cat /home/alice/flag22
39 64 31 61 65 38 64 35 36 39 63 38 33 65 30 33 64 38 61 38 66 36 31 35 36 38 61 30 66 61 37 64
```

When I pipe that into the [`xxd`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) and convert to hex characters, I only get a subset of the entire string

```
cat /home/alice/flag22 | xxd -r
d1ae8d569c83e03d
```

I am expecting the entire string to be `9d1ae8d569c83e03d8a8f61568a0fa7d` (using an online tool).

Somehow the `9d` and the `8a8f61568a0fa7d` were removed.

> 9d `1ae8d569c83e03d` 8a8f61568a0fa7d

Am I not using the `xxd` tool correctly? (Looked through `man xxd` but didn't find anything obvious).

Comment: that's probably ascii not hexadecimal. I don't see any abcdef in that long string of "39 64 31 61......."

Comment: This question, a capture the flag challenge, it's  basically a puzzle and not useful to anybody.  If you had a specific issue with xxd then it shouldn't be stuck within a capture the flag challenge

Comment: Thanks for noting my error, Barlop. I've reworded my question.

Comment: @Roger I was perhaps a bit confused.. it is a puzzle. But yeah ascii can be in hex or decimal.  http://www.asciitable.com/   if it's in hex then xxd would apply. But it might not be in hex it might be in decimal . I'm not really a puzzle person. There's no A-F though that doesn't mean it's not hex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the `-p` (plain) option to `xxd` like this:

```
cat /home/alice/flag22 | xxd -r -p
```

The output I get when I do that in Bash on macOS 10.5.6 (Catalina) seems to be exactly what you are looking for:

```
9d1ae8d569c83e03d8a8f61568a0fa7d
```

According to `man xxd` the `-p` option does the following:

> Output  in  postscript  continuous  hexdump style. Also known as plain hexdump style.

And deeper in the `man xxd` stuff under `-r` (revert) option explains it as so; bold emphasis is mine:

> Reverse operation: convert (or patch) hexdump into  binary. If not  writing  to stdout, xxd writes into its output file without truncating it. **Use the combination `-r` `-p` to read plain hexadecimal dumps without line number information and without a particular column layout.** Additional Whitespace and line-breaks are allowed anywhere.

Since that long string hex dump you have has no line or column info, the `-p` option is what is needed.